# Why is this block of code converting some value back to Nan?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame 'cars', with a column 'price'. Originally, it had 4 null values. Using:

```
cars = cars.dropna(subset=['price'])
```

I dropped those rows. Then I created a new data frame, numeric_cars, with only numeric data. Price at this point still had no null values. However, when I try to normalize all values except price in this new data frame, the 4 null values return. I realize I can just drop them again, but why is this happening? Here is the normalizing code:

```
numeric_cars['price'].isnull().sum() #Output 0
from sklearn import preprocessing
price_col = numeric_cars['price'].copy()
x = numeric_cars.values #returns a numpy array
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
x_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(x)
numeric_cars = pd.DataFrame(x_scaled, columns = numeric_cols)
numeric_cars['price'] = price_col
numeric_cars['price'].isnull().sum() #Output 4
```

Comment: you need to provide a [mcve] please read [ask] and also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Answer (score 0):

A min_max_scaler will transform that data by doing `x = (x - min) / (max - min)`.

Are you sure there isn't any column with constant values? i.e. min=max? Maybe it's getting a division by 0 and generating the NaN's.

Comment: Why would this result in only 4 null values though? If min = max for a column, wouldn't every value become NaN?